# Giving weights to an instance according to a normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, matlab, variance

I am currently working on a project where we have a distance with a normal distribution, and want to give weights to readings based on the distribution.

i.e: if the distance between two points is given to be a normal distribution with mean= 5 meters and sigma = 1 meter,  and my reading about the distance gives 5.1 meters, i want to give this reading more weight than a reading that gives 5.9 meters because according to the normal distribution, 5.1 is more probable than 5.9.
i have found a function in matlab ( normpdf ) that would map it based on the probability of occurrence. i.e. error =0 maps to 0.4

Now I want to know how is this normalized so that the sum of probabilities for all readings would be equal to 1.

Comment: I would suggest giving a weight of simply the value of the "bell curve", $\phi(x)$, the equation of the normal distribution density function.

Comment: In this case it would be
$$
\phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2 }} e^{- \frac{ \left( x - \mu \right)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}
$$

Comment: Now the sum of all readings is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(x) dx = 1$

Comment: Thanks matti for your answer, but i didnt understand how  ∫∞−∞ϕ(x)dx=1 when i have 1000 readings for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let there be $n$ samples then define your weight for the $i^{th}$ sample as

$W_i = \frac{e^{\frac{{(x_i-5)}^2}{2}}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{e^{\frac{{(x_i-5)}^2}{2}}}}$

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I was too immersed in the problem solving that I couldn't understand first.